# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in Twig

Tags: twig

I create twig template with structure

```
main.twig has block content with include 'card.twig'

card.twig extends 'main.twig' and realise block content with block secondContent include 'rec.twig

rec.twig extends 'card.twig' and realise block secondContent
```

But I have RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Why?

Comment: Could you paste some code? Your question is unclear without code.

Comment: U made an infinite loop with that set-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create infinite loop. I solve it by below scheme

```
main.twig has block content with include 'card.twig'

card.twig realise block content with block secondContent include 'rec.twig'

rec.twig realise block secondContent
```